# Google safe browsing API: unable to download list

Tags: javascript, php, curl, google-api, malware-detection

I am using Google safe browsing API V3 to check if accessed URLs are safe or not. But it always returns 0.

Below is my code:

```
function googleDownloader($url)
    {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $headr[] = 'Content-length: 10000';
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$headr);
    $body = 'googpub-phish-shavar; goog-malware-shavar; goog-unwanted-shavar;';
    $buildopts = array(CURLOPT_POST=>true,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS=>$body."\n");
    if(is_array($buildopts))
        curl_setopt_array($ch, $buildopts);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT ,1); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 1000);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
    if ($data === false)
    {
        // throw new Exception('Curl error: ' . curl_error($crl));
        print_r('Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch));
    }
    //echo $code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    curl_close($ch);        
    return array($info,$data);      
    }

    $url = "https://safebrowsing.google.com/safebrowsing/downloads?client=api&key=mygoogleapikey&appver=1.5.2&pver=3.0";
    $result =  googleDownloader($url);
```

I want it to result in a list that I can encode and store in my database.

I tried from past two day but no success. Please help me to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

If I call below url using curl it give some non readable result

```
http://safebrowsing-cache.google.com/safebrowsing/rd/ChRnb29ncHViLXBoaXNoLXNoYXZhcjgBQAJKDAgBEOKrARj-qwEgAUoMCAEQ1qsBGOCrASABSgwIARC7qwEY1KsBIAFKDAgBELirARi5qwEgAUoMCAEQsKsBGLarASABSgwIARCgqwEYrqsBIAFKDAgBEJerARieqwEgAUoMCAEQlKsBGJWrASABSgwIARCSqwEYkqsBIAFKDAgBEIKrARiQqwEgAUoMCAEQ_6oBGP-qASABSgwIARD7qgEY_aoBIAFKDAgBEPKqARj4qgEgAUoMCAEQ6KoBGPCqASABSgwIARDjqgEY5qoBIAFKDAgBENuqARjhqgEgAUoMCAEQ06oBGNmqASABSgwIARDRqgEY0aoBIAFKDAgBEMOqARjOqgEgAUoMCAEQvqoBGMGqASABSgwIARC5qgEYu6oBIAFKDAgBELCqARi3qgEgAUoMCAEQpqoBGK6qASABSgwIARCgqgEYpKoBIAFKDAgBEJqqARieqgEgAUoMCAEQj6oBGJiqASABSgwIARDtqQEYjaoBIAFKDAgBEOepARjrqQEgAUoMCAEQ4qkBGOWpASABSgwIARDbqQEY4KkBIAFKDAgBENmpARjZqQEgAUoMCAEQ0qkBGNWpASABSgwIARDNqQEY0KkBIAFKDAgBEMqpARjLqQEgAUoMCAEQxKkBGMipASABSgwIARC-qQEYwakBIAFKDAgBELupARi7qQEgAUoMCAEQuKkBGLmpASABSgwIARC2qQEYtqkBIAFKDAgBEK-pARixqQEgAUoMCAEQrakBGK2pASABSgwIARCrqQEYq6kBIAFKDAgBEKipARipqQEgAUoMCAEQpqkBGKapASABSgwIARCjqQEYo6kBIAFKDAgBEJypARigqQEgAUoMCAEQmqkBGJqpASABSgwIARCVqQEYmKkBIAFKDAgBEJGpARiTqQEgAUoMCAEQjqkBGI-pASABSgwIARCLqQEYjKkBIAFKDAgBEIWpARiIqQEgAUoMCAEQg6kBGIOpASABSgwIARD-qAEYgKkBIAFKDAgBEPeoARj4qAEgAUoMCAEQ9agBGPWoASABSgwIARDvqAEY86gBIAFKDAgBEOyoARjsqAEgAUoMCAEQ5KgBGOqoASABSgwIARDgqAEY4agBIAFKDAgBEN6oARjeqAEgAUoMCAEQ2agBGNuoASABSgwIARDXqAEY16gBIAFKDAgBENGoARjRqAEgAUoMCAEQyagBGMyoASABSgwIARDGqAEYxqgBIAFKDAgBELuoARjBqAEgAUoMCAEQuagBGLmoASABSgwIARCzqAEYtKgBIAFKDAgBELCoARixqAEgAUoMCAEQrqgBGK6oASABSgwIARCpqAEYqagBIAFKDAgBEKaoARinqAEgAUoMCAEQpKgBGKSoASABSgwIARCaqAEYmqgBIAE
```

I get following response

**â«" =6‹*À²ã«"êH*Ç²ä«"%J~èø0Qð*€²Æ²å«"AØëE\3*Ì²²æ«"×´zŠ*Ñ²ç«"K©*Ñ²è«"kÔ¿Fc¯*Ö²Ö²-é«"
òÃ¤š¥&[;dõœpë#o*Ø²Ø²Ð²Ð²×²ê«"ÆgY*À²ë«"'õŠ*Ü²ì«"Hû]ù.ã•}ú•*   Þ²Þ²Þ²í«"‘
û*â²î«"»µ‰*ë²ï«"-ò0b*ñ²ð«"HÌà}*õ²ñ«"V¤ô8J$#+¸*  Ä²Ä²ÿ±ò«"LS\?ûø*÷²÷²ó«"þ6UC*Û²ô«"÷H¯
*€³õ«"£…v£A¨>ò*ó²·²ö«"(ÚæM*³÷«"Så¯…*…³ø«"šå G*ˆ³ù«"«—=i¹!*Ž³¿²ú«"_Ã1þSçY*©®“³û«"¥‘èÖ*º²ü«"ô
,¸*ž³&ý«"h8œ¾Òc2lZøK.aïÅõ*¤³™³™³Ô²þ«"ZÄdÓ*¦³Ö«"aÖÌ*£­×«"²>“Ê*ù¬Ø«"°f7*³²Ù«"­¼ß%*…ÿÚ«"çGõ*©²Û«"5ø˜£9[*ý±»²Ü«"i{ví˜*¼²±Ý«"ð/nÇþé*º²·²Þ«">"‚0*¹²ß«"÷Õ**Ê¡à«"TµI*Ã²»«"»Œ¯*—¼«"€îîG*šŒ½«"Ü£*ä¦¾«"|(¥Íï¯*‚®¼°¿«"L¶#GTv~*á™šÝÀ«"%ù!*€‘Á«"šó ÅÍcù*ý®ý®Â«"fU£Í;Ø*«¯«¯Ã«"­­·£2ÛnÑòZ*    ö—§­§­Ä«"Me-*‚±Å«"§c  hš
û*ÖªÆ«"ÞHn4®ç'…ex5* Ž°’¯’¯Ç«"ï Â*š±È«"HgÍ*¸ªÉ«"øççç*ÀœÊ«"ÿê^²*æ©Ë«"ÜG)Çƒ*¡*é°ù°Ì«"w-cÅ*þ¤Í«"¼ƒ|ù*­±Î«"BÆŸé¹þ[*ë±Œ±Ï«"Ióç«*ü±Ð«"í™>ÜËT“*É±·±Ñ«"Ê*î±Ò«"V Ê*²Ó«"Ö-‰¶*Õ®Ô«"¾Ì/òïMV/*Ð’Î’¸«"Y…‰µ*‘­¹«":šŒð*—¯°«"¶V2*Ž­±«"@4*¾ ²«"¹*­Š³«"žEH8aQÄ*—úº£-´«"`ùÁÓüw@’/vÓ‚8”-6*ß®™¦§¢¶¦™¦µ«"\È*ñ…¶«"Æ2Å=Ûí¾
Û°* †Á«Ð­ «"ža­Õ*–¦¡«"ÿE*Ø¬¢«"UtO•*˜¬£«"£·¨œ$Q~* £ £¤«"Æög¶]½FÏ*ÿñç•&¥«"!ãmÎ4ŽšÓù AWò*‹š×™þ£•¨¦«"­~’V*õ¬§«"£Æ'å*¦ª¨«"¤>&GLÑÆdt”*  ¦¥©¥¦¥&©«"üZJ·3?†ç]6z*„£ê¦ž¤žª«"Ì1£ê*Ö«««"–Äó*’­¬«"[E*{*î§­«"  ßE„*ž’®«"ö†*•‡—«"ƒ%W¢*Ó©˜«"µ{¹’i:Ä*É£»£™«"Æ}D*§©š«"'é½q˜%ª*ŸªŸª›«"ÚÌ‘H*É’œ«"Xãô¬*ü©«";3,¯*Ò Ò ž«"“K]*†¤”«"ü®_ý²žC*ç¤³¤•«"é¦Ž0Ìæ‹Ç*Ê¥Ö¨’«" s .*È§‚«"¬é*ðŽƒ«"Æ{Tò¸»w*è£©¡„«"ŒQ5²*è¤…«"'©*ä£&†«"Œ-]‘£€söÛXWì*æÝì’æÝîÝ‡«"d.¨*¡¥ˆ«"ùY±í*ï¤‰«"„¾ ¿Åbp*é£¨¥Š«"r®v*“¦‹«"ÈÔàˆBÕ÷‡QÎZÌ*   ù¤’¥š¦Œ«"†ýMå*è™«"‡_­*“¥Ž«"Ï^-A*8¨*ŸÎ¡Î¡Ÿðª"ÓÖØ*ø¢ãª"Q‰Í*Å äª"+º*s*è¡åª"ïûÁ4M½„©¹*   ™ž’œ’œæª"øÜRE*­›Ûª"Õõ>¹ý?íœ9G*    ‹••‹•Üª"30˜ù*é›Ýª"Sàtð*øžÞª"¿Z¹‹¬Yùë^r2* Úú Ý€ßª"2#>(*´œàª"L
”G*Ó€áª"ÄõX6*‡ž&Óª"ªÃ’LóŸ£¼*©qÝeâé*»›ÈÞÀÖºÞÔª"¢Í¦*˜Õª"Qi‡H*‰šÖª"™RQDT/î*É“É“×ª"#U~*ûžØª"£Ô†«*ƒœÙª"¥/Q‘*õŸÑª"ÅT@*‰žÃª"9HC*¹œÄª"E>P^0„l¶h*   ÕœÓœ¶›Åª"}Rç9*Ù›Æª"½ó1tñX$*Úœ¡™Çª"Å}ó–Nz*¶¹™Èª"S=­lIžF*ó™ó™Éª"“Gz*úœÊª"¶zFƒ]óM*ïœïœËª"žŽ‚*“Ìª"‹ÚIY*Ô™Íª"ø]ô*‘“ãÎª"|üvâºÐbÝn‘@x6L%áôJ'w„jb®)`Œ2ÏÝ^ÒùðW¹½w7zÚØž‡k+\Y§*«4 õa‘gæ7”n „M´gÝ1<Ãq0 S~Ñ{•¹·)™4} ¶žÈX!Þ‰k›°T‰·×÷’ˆµ³Ú*]çñ þþœþ•þ•þôöõö¿÷¾÷®ù­ø¦ù­ùÂø®ø¨ùéù»ù·ù¼ùÙùºùÙù¾ùÃùºù»ù½ùŠûŒû¾ª"Ñ×Þ–Ê·@*¯›¯›¿ª"Ä„²*¢•Àª"‰GEz*û™Áª"Ev*º›¹ª"}‰¬~*ù—ºª"õb*õš»ª"Cù0q*Ö›°ª"¦JH×*ò˜±ª"‹· i*ë–²ª"«¿x¨*œ™³ª"ÇoNû>3*œ–˜–´ª"ýpY¹*ñ‹µª"ì¶×¾Ñ/q*…Œ®‹¶ª"âÀZB*ô™·ª"’’¨M*©™¦ª"p>Ê*§ª"s!-“=«*á•á•¨ª"¶èÕ*Ž“©ª"‡-ß{èK‰—*­—ë–ªª"ø¬QC*â—«ª"ü~d*…Š¬ª"´ÖD*ö­ª"ç¸Û*’™®ª"¸<*a*Õ ª"h¡ç*:À9ã*®‘¡æ¡ª"she*ÿ”¢ª"O„v¯Ç™ùÚ*ØÅ£ª"k/¥*Ð–¤ª"cê‘T9A5*«—º–šª"o/K*ð›ª"ç¸y-°Nv*ë–Žœª"‰€÷¬*Ó–ª"3ÄbÃ^µ°*º‹Žþžª"< @Ø˜oíª*ÉŸ–ª"îù¬çjE“ér* æé¢•Ë”ª"¿ªbÒ DR~Ù«ø* ûÿåÿñÿ‘ª"fäU3“¥‹*–»¶‹’ª"BÙ>*“•“ª"àrS*ë–”ª"Jžë*¦‘•ª" ²C*›€–ª"];û5*ôŠ—ª"7/?û*í‰˜ª"´ºŠc*„•í©"/&‘*¨‘î©"ÇÒŽûœ4Â*°Œ·ƒï©"O¤Ex*¿‘ð©"þ°x%*Áñ©"«q~'*î‘ò©"Eq=â*¸‘ó©";&ƒ    Ñ˜T*¥‘Ÿ‘ô©"¿æµŒ*ÌÜõ©"x­(ÍˆÎi…êøB.7íùQT7;(Ï@×²    ;ÈôÒìáuW±~t
Q)äH\x:RÃëµæ­éKáØW ÙL.
bçùÝŠ¤îènaÒfëº   îfÐF¿ßú»óåÓ½%¡zS=çÂ`šQXÅW2ÝððA*ZÃ­¸Ö†òýƒ¹¢¶ÅËåù¢±ñÈ²ºµ¦Ô’øöÇÅºµš¸¢ÛÌÊª»á²‘Ä“ÿÔ‡éõÆŠ´Šþö©"€´©@jÎw#ëá* ¢’¢’‘÷©"RR0)*¹Œø©"¦«
* ’ù©"uõ6ô/ké*›“›“ú©"»`éƒÍ*Í‚†ÿû©"%NéC*³”ü©"ì÷ñßd(*“Š•ý©"²g6*«’þ©"‚T÷ÅT;‘hÑ)*  ÊŒæ€ó’ÿ©"iv“g*Ä“€ª"ì;#*øª"·B(¤*ÝŒ‚ª"j„U*ûƒª"ºêœ!{ãa*¶­•„ª"4%R½ªw*ó–ô…ª"ÆÕf—*‰”†ª"©òã*£•‡ª"+ßÇà?‡*‰‚¡ˆª"R-C[*á•‰ª"lçÜBãb>©*·’º•Šª"³Ã~*þŠ‹ª"sÿF‰*Æÿ-Œª"7ÕaZÜ´o‡¬Úµoþ‚¡Æ_2*¢¢­£¢ª"ZŠ\ê*º”ç©"Ò§Ä¸*Êè©"R'¡*»‘é©"Oø@*Ýê©"
n¢¹*÷Šë©"Á5$*€€4â©"¯1µ*¸úþ:«¦ùD–Ïv2r)j´x*ÊÚ÷Ûâìâìâæó4ã©"E–ÿëiüäêI$Ó"ptI†€ß*ãæåì÷åä©"ˆµ¿*Ž‘å©"ˆY×
jöwÉ"TLÎ`í±±N™„„ˆ4$Ìòm6Ü×°°>ß_vï»Ùö´(4¸x`3z[ÈÀÂx\ï®‡À˜¤*WåååååååååååååååååååååååååååååÕ©"—¼¦ân7¹*ÝÈƒÍ©"’µ±ÅZ8ÉÀ*ýŽÈÔÎ©"DKŒ*ÓWÏ©",NRˆq»Æ»ÛmÀÂ¢ƒÌHh@Eé*ƒåhù]žK‚-àæi€à¢Î…€—)*!äääääääääää‰Ð©"ìh“Á]àþàØÀgkâÍ¨¤<³V¤—öÊâ±xN*gÞ*LúÚ=iPí‘ìxyp`Â·»ÀXŠ©bgA™ÿÃ­>+„@_NËˆ¦Ý6—^
Knn?Å€\¼_T;ÈÐ¨#/!}Fœ6„øŽðÒBÐ¦(A)ô¯&¢1³6eÛˆ…
Hðz/ÈA´fþgø‡‘E©éAce~úÌó,6÷F-|ídk#§/èP¢Iú%×œÆ´«üdÏ–øîb¢{f@†=vn™' ªÊ-ê{7Q9˜v¬¾<]Ó¥®2èZ/u’¾pq´ÞÅþ¹GFìÃ¹µ$ÀnîŽåZL–Š¥*ÐØ°žïnª^›ãõqQ)–î±&¥@]Nn@Ä6»-ëÜ=êyjþ
eà‘š[gh?Ê™ŽC¢
3U¢æ?ð§²   nI¯š`{-NQ3÷ò©§Æ/¿>YŒP"#°[‡Ï;*‘äääääääääääääääääääääääääääääääääääääääääääääååååååååååååååååååååååååååååååååååååååååååååååÊ©"1^*¬‹Ë©"÷9i*«ŽÄ©"CÒp!Åoæw*øŽøŽÅ©"ÖˆÀ*ƒŽÆ©"Lš¹UŽ*›ŠíŠÇ©"" 0*Ó‚È©"'Äi*È¾©"!ÍË*ñ€¿©"¤í0âb€p*¦ßÚÀ©"x…Ä*ÀÁ©"p1È*ÿŠ»©"ùïp¼*Æˆ¸©"H"e‚úÚŸôßc—±"?qemP®wÔÛ¥%§×Z
Ån4Hµ“Fø¥ÑãõPü¥ äGûac‰T¶8PíPº@Tðˆë:´É;Y*6ÈÞÈÞåÃ³ÞåÃßÐ‡Þ¤Þ¤Þ¥ÞÒÉŠÉËÈçêÉíÈüÈç–¹©"P×Íí²Âò­©ùõø:Jn+ª¸©Uøv÷ïé…iÓkÚ˜Ó«*³
Å=Þì\'=MÐ½5ßl< ïÌ]#|}N£¼ÊÝ÷kŽNCû6ÄÅ*<ÂÈÛÉÉ“ÉüÈ‘ÉµÈŽÉç›ÉàÈÑÈÄÉ‰ÉšÉ÷ÈèÈ‰ÉÖÈç¶©")=Mn*°Œ¯©"Î¸²*Ç°©"‘fÔ¤Ú4=ç¾¹*    ¶Š¶Š¶Š±©"&³*ÍŠ­©"†K½Š*º‹«©"ª^~*Ö‹¨©"òŒDL*Ý†©©"IHû*Œ¦©"ç"*Œ£©"_Ðo*¸ƒœ©"Í«ýä*‹‹©"}:m*€‹ž©"$ÏÖ¡%U*œŠ¯‹Ÿ©"hnèK*é‰B ©" ×2ñ9pržÓ²â±ÇÿP×
æ“Ñ‚m6†è»Dé0*¦óòŠÇŠ¦óêºòŠðŠêºš©"¡Þ,*²†•©"zx.  *‡–©"î~ê*¯‰—©"Ïp*÷‰˜©"|W*ÀŠ‘©"›vÜûye•I*¢‰‡&’©"ˆú,R
Q·¾Áþ6…jº³*€‰Ž‰”‰Ÿ‰“©"ýJ|?…î€v}Üí*  ‰àÇ‰€€Ž©"þô@
*—ˆ©"„—Eœ*Ï€‹©"»¸!—Ÿs»¸Vbëõ*   Øûôû††Œ©"ñ]\P*òƒ…©"MnR*©…†©"«o£ì*Àˆ‡©"0üî*ëþˆ©"(*ý*ü„Wƒ©",Òß$fáí+¬¾H u&ôq¬k|óãÙpêGCË:l%“„a5˜ÁÃÉ,)*!Øà»àëà¿àÙÞõéàåßÞßÜ¿â‡þ¨"54& *±†ÿ¨"¡ÃS‚ìh*Í†²†€©"Çpè±Î3ì*ðƒåƒ÷¨"ÆØ/¢ïÂ²Ä*ÚËÙÿø¨".µæ  *À†§†õ¨"éÊ6\ƒÅ*ªþÒï¨"£DÌWX 
*Øƒïùð¨"ã4*ù„ñ¨"Añ/*…ò¨"Em~­ôÊÇM“*  Á‚…îèó¨"úÊD.*‘‚ì¨"Øìv*ƒ…ä¨">{…!8èÓ¶* ƒïñƒå¨":¸Ç”*çƒæ¨"†£´n*†ƒç¨"Å×ò*Ëÿè¨"æ·„‰Ñø“*Ä„Ä„é¨"á<¶V*î„ê¨"R#>Ú·«Ã¤*¶ìì„à¨"›ÒÃ$¨(Â*²ýÛƒá¨"G¢]*ÅôûÞ¨"ŸX*¸Ù¨"*€=Ÿ*ô‚Ú¨"Ê>ÜN*ÄÛ¨"å^8É§þ9*Ÿþ¿ü×¨"|=MF­*««Ñ¨"–´°Ø…,¬l*ççÉ¨"KÚ®v*ºÊ¨"Ù–ÝV*²þË¨"Ê_û•,Õì'én    *   ‚Ž‚ÁÌ¨"‹    0*‚ÿÆ¨"S•h{*“€»¨"ü›ˆ***“€¼¨"WMÌ¿væŠøý¾€½¨"¿ûy¢­7  ë÷ÿ4*  €«ü«ü&¾¨"£›Ä¶îùåæò§¾Ž…²*€Ñéò€—¿¨"­
=Æžš*åÿÊôÀ¨"]Ñ)s*êÿÁ¨"²×Ø*÷ÿ¹¨"ê(e*Ç€³¨"¼êß*ìþ´¨"jmÛÈ*Óÿ°¨"1ÉáÇ*ßÿ±¨"õ#Ü*Çþ®¨"Ö|¸*®þ©¨"LRèv*¨þ¦¨"Ÿ0 5*‰ÿ§¨"˜µl’f¡"*ëÚãþ¤¨"ú§Õ**¾þš¨"¶í*ùý**